# Problems deploying Pyramid with uWSGI on Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, pyramid, web-deployment, init

I seem to be having some slight problems deploying a Pyramid web application. The problem seems to lie in my init script that I am using to start my web application on boot. For some reason, uWSGI will not work unless my socket is set to have a permission of "nobody.nobody" OR Nginx is started after my uwsgi init script. I'm changed my init script to reflect these changes, but it does not seem to be working. The init script (or the part that starts uwsgi) looks like so:

```
#!/sbin/runscript
args="--ini-paste /var/www/pyramid/app1/development.ini"
command="/var/www/pyramid/bin/uwsgi"
pidfile="/var/run/uwsgi.pid"
sock="/var/tmp/proxy/uwsgi.sock"
nobody="nobody.nobody"

start() {
  ebegin "Starting app1"
  chown $nobody $sock
  start-stop-daemon --start --exec $command -- $args \
      --pidfile $pidfile 
  chown $nobody $sock
  einfo "app1 started"
  eend $?
}
```

My Nginx configuration looks like so:

```
location / { 
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/tmp/proxy/uwsgi.sock;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "" ;
}
```

My ini file includes the following:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/tmp/proxy/uwsgi.sock
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi.pid
master = true
processes = 1
home = /var/www/pyramid
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi.log
virtualenv = /var/www/pyramid/
pythonpath = /var/www/pyramid/bin
```

What happens is that Nginx will start, and then uwsgi will start. Performing a "ls -la" in /var/tmp/proxy reveals that the permissions of uwsgi.sock is set to "root root" instead of "nobody nobody". However, restarting Nginx will fix the problem, regardless of what the socket's permissions are (but Nginx has to be started first).

Thus, the ways I can get this to work is:

- start uwsgi
- start nginx
- restart nginx

or

- start nginx
- start uwsgi
- restart nginx

I'm at a complete loss as to why this isn't working. If anyone has any advice I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following settings to change the permission of its socket in your ini file:

```
chmod-socket = 777 # socket permission
gid = www-data # socket group 
uid = www-data # socket user
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is whether you actually want uWSGI to run as root. If you pass --uid and --gid arguments to uwsgi, uwsgi will masquerade as a different (preferably non-root) user.

For example, nginx usually runs as the www-data user and www-data group. So if you set up your wsgi app to run with "--gid www-data" and then add at least group-write permissions to your socket file with "--chmod-socket 020", then nginx will be able to write to the socket and you'll be in business.

See my blog post on the subject: http://blog.jackdesert.com/common-hurdles-to-deploying-uwsgi-apps-part-1